# Version Requirements for iOS development

Tags: ios, xcode

I am an experienced developer starting on my first iOS project.  I am comfortable with the hardware and software that I will be using, but confused about the dependencies between the various components to achieve what I need to do.

Here's what I have:

- iMac 21.5 inch, i5 processor 2011 vintage
- OSX 10.7.5
- XCode 4.2.1
- iOS SDK 5.0/4.3/4.2
- iPhone 4 running iOS 7

I first became aware of a problem, when XCode refused to let me download the app I am developing to the device.  Presumably because I am targeting iOS 5, while the phone is on iOS 7.

I am hesitant to rush off and upgrade everything, as I am aware with Apple this is often a one-way street.  For example, I bought the iPhone second hand that the vender had already upgraded to iOS 7, and now I cannot downgrade.

Here's what I want to be able to do:

- Use my current hardware for development
- Publish new apps in the App Store
- Test my app on my iPhone (and preferably older models also)
- Support iOS7 plus as many older iOS versions as possible
- If possible, have the app use older controls styling (-iOS6) on iOS7

Can someone help me with my thought process through the various dependencies, and what versions I am going to need to achieve these aims?

Comment: If you want to develop for Apple platforms you need to accept the fact that you'll (often) need the newest versions in order to work with their policies. You should upgrade to Mavericks and Xcode 5, and you shouldn't even be thinking about iOS 5 or below anymore.

Comment: You should barely even be thinking about `iOS6` even.  I've heard that `iOS7` already has over a 65% adoption rate.

Comment: To the question of whether or not you can implement the pre-iOS7 look on an iOS7 device... you can.  But it's a TON of extra legwork, a major headache, and to what end?  In a couple months, the result is that the end user will think of your app as old or out of date, no matter how frequently you update the app, because it LOOKS like an old app while the rest of us are updating our apps to adopt the `iOS7` look.

Comment: according to what was my past experience with the Mac OS SDKs, you have way too much requirements, if you want to develop for iOS and Mac devices you simply stick with what Apple gives to you at any point in time, if Apple decides that your mac is too old or your Xcode is too old, that's it, you have to change. Also remember that some software with some given licenses is banned from being used in your application ( if I remember correctly GPL licensed code is banned plus maybe another 1-2 kind of licenses ), your application is also subject to any kind of censorship and "approval process".

Comment: so be sure you understand how Apple "thinks" and what is the set of rules that you are supposed to follow.

Comment: You can make your buttons, nav bars, tab bars, etc, look HOWEVER you want.  Many apps have plenty of custom looks to all of these very standard UI Elements.  But forcing a pre-iOS7 look on an iOS7 device is done the SAME way you'd put an entirely custom look on your app.  And if you're going to do that, you should actually do a custom look rather than replicating a look that will make your app feel out of date.

Comment: Thanks all, is there some minimum requirement that Apple enforces for app submission, in terms of Xcode or iOS target version?  I had heard there was, but haven't been able to confirm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll still be able to develop for iOS6 and earlier if you have the latest version of XCode, just set your deployment target accordingly. With XCode 5 though Apple stopped including the iOS5 simulators and earlier, so you would have to manually download it and include it if you wanted to use that.

Note that to develop with a real device (not just on the Simulator), you need to have an Apple Developer license and have added the device through the Developer portal.

Comment: Thanks @ebi, but then it looks like to run Xcode 5 I will need to upgrade OSX to 10.8. http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tools-utilities/114084-will-xcode-5-run-on-lion.html  Do you think that it where the upgrade dependencies end?  Thanks for the extra comment, yes, I have an Apple Developer account already.

Comment: You should update to `OSX 10.9`, which, by the way, is a free upgrade.

Comment: @nhgrif thanks, any downside to 10.9 with two year old hardware?

Comment: No.  The machine I develop on at work is a 2011 model, I believe.  10.9 and 10.8 have the exact same hardware requirements.

Comment: @stephen 10.9 works fine on my 2010 MBP, didn't cause any problems when upgrading.

Comment: You do not need to download iOS 5. Xcode 5 allows you to set the "Deployment Target" back to iOS 4.3. No need to download anything else. Of course this assumes your Base SDK will be iOS 7.0.

Comment: @rmaddy You are correct. I was thinking about the versions available for the simulator. Comment updated.